# Creating VRT or index of large amount of aerial images to create mosaic in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-3

I have about 1600 aerial images that I want to create a mosaic of. I tried doing about 400 at a time in a VRT, it's extremely slow (been building polygons for about 15 minutes now + the 20 minutes it took to build the VRT). Is there a more efficent way to do this, like by creating an index somehow?

To be honest I don't know exactly what that entails, but I noticed at my job we keep large amounts of tiles indexed in an excel file, you load the file into arcmap and bam you've got a snappy large scale mosaic. Can I do something to the same effect in QGIS?

Comment: "I tried doing about 400 at a time in a VRT" - can you tell us more about what you did here?

Comment: The dataset I downloaded had multiple file types (e.g. jp2, aux, j2w, xml, dbf, etc.). Within the create VRT tool under the raster dropdown I selected all the jp2 files for one-quarter (400) of my aerials; they comprised the north-western part of the mosaic I wish to create. Boxes for separating inputs into separate bands, allowing projection differences(all are in the same CRS), and adding alpha mask band left untouched; used nearest for re sampling and saved to file. This worked, but rendering was extremely slow when panning and changing scales; tried to build pyramids, failed.

Answer (score 3):

A VRT is basically a list of files with instructions, so it's a lot like the idea of an Excel spreadsheet of tiles. The software can read the list and decide what to do. What's really neat about VRTs is that you can chain them together to do a bunch of processing steps. Since processing a VRT just adds to the instructions of what to do with each file, each individual step is very fast. Then when you're ready to create a real output all the steps get run at once, and you don't have to generate files for all the intermediate steps. Here's an overview: [Lazy Raster Processing](http://www.perrygeo.com/lazy-raster-processing-with-gdal-vrts.html).

So in the case of QGIS, the program can read the list and decide which images to show. It looks like your image tiles also came with a shapefile (a bunch of files with the same file name and the extensions .shp, .shx, .dbf, and maybe some others). That's a file that stores the polygons of the tiles. Some software, like ArcView, can use this polygons to decide which images to display, and with spatial indexing tricks you can find those images very quickly. Unfortunately QGIS doesn't do this. It does offer the tool to build a tile index file, but for display it only reads the VRT to figure out which images to display. That's still better than trying to access the image files themselves.

So why is the display slow even with a VRT? Not knowing your data, I'm going to guess that it has to do with the image tiles - I don't have benchmarking but decompressing JP2 files might not be the fastest way to access the data. I would also guess that the files don't have overviews, which are lower resolution versions of the files that the software can read when it displays the image when it's zoomed out. So when you try to view say 75 tiles, you have to read the full resolution of those 75 tiles.

When you load imagery into ArcMap for the first time, it asks if you want to build overviews. So my guess is that those overviews are the reason you're seeing the faster loading, not the Excel file.

Is there an easy solution you're missing? Sorry, no. There's two things you can do:

1. Convert the files to a format that reads faster and has overviews. QGIS does have a tool for this but it sounds like it crashed when you ran it on the VRT. You may have to convert them outside of QGIS. This article talks about converting to compressed TIFFs and in my experience it does speed things up: [Geotiff Compression for Dummies](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/02/geotiff-compression-for-dummies.html). You can then wrap them all in a VRT to make it easy to use in QGIS.
2. Set up a WMS server to create and cache tiles, ideally with the optimized images above. This is a lot more work but if this is a layer you and your colleagues will use a lot it might be worth it.

Comment: Thanks I'll give option 1 a try for now; this is not needed for work, but a personal exercise I am doing. You talked about the problems with jp2, but when I look at the index my co-worker created, its five columns: a file pathway (which leads to a jp2), and then minimum and maximum extents for rendering the images (so four columns; 2 for min x and y, 2 for max). My point being it seems that this file does not point to a shape file but the jp2, and the performance is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: It's hard to say exactly from over here. If you open the VRT file (it's just XML so you can use any text editor) you'll see that it's also just paths and descriptions about the image. If your colleague is using ArcView, it might have build overview and previews automatically which will make it run much faster. QGIS doesn't do this so you have to do the conversion yourself. There also could be differences in the JP2 decoding libraries.

Comment: Not sure if they used ArcView but; when I add the layer to ArcMap it is inside an excel file and has a $ symbol in front of it.